# CoreData: when is it okay to use several fetchResultsControllers?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Still in my RSS reader development, I use the following model:

```
Categorie -> Feed -> Post
```

For my Master View Controller, I want to display the number of unread Posts (Posts which `read` NSDate is `nil`) next to the category name.

As I need an NSFetchResultsController to select the Categories, do I need another one to get the `Category.feeds.posts.read == nil` count?

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a separate fetched results controller.

The way I understand your question: you want to display a list of categories. With each category name you want to display the count of unread messages.

I would implement a fetched property in your `Category` class like this.

```
@implementation Category ()

-(NSUInteger)unreadMessages {
   NSUInteger count = 0;
   for (Feed *feed in self.feeds) {
      NSSet *posts = [feed.posts filteredSetUsingPredicate
       [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"read = null"]];
      count += posts.count
   }
   return count;
}

@end
```

It would be even more efficient, I think, if you would introduce a flag property `unread` (rename `read` to `firstReadDate`) with default set to `1` for post:

```
for (Feed *feed in self.feeds) {
  count += [[feed.posts valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.unread"] integerValue];
}
```

Comment: Hello Mundi, thanks for your help. So I may edit the generated Coredata classes with such methods? That'd be great!

Comment: Absolutely! Even better is to make categories (`Category+Extension.h`) so you have it in a separate file. If the model should change you can re-generate the class files without overwriting your custom code.

Comment: I will try that and mark this question as resolved as soon as it works. Thanks!